# Is branch prediction purely cpu behavior, or will the compiler give some hints?

Tags: go, compiler-optimization, branch-prediction

In go standard package src/sync/once.go, a recent revision change the snippets

```
if atomic.LoadUint32(&o.done) == 1 {
        return
    }
//otherwise
...
```

to:

```
//if atomic.LoadUint32(&o.done) == 1 {
//      return
//  }
if atomic.LoadUint32(&o.done) == 0 {
        ...
    }
```

the question is, according to this change, hot path is no longer explicit in the code, does this change has bad impact on branch prediction ? does go compiler make some help in the subsequent run of this function or the whole thing of branch prediction is on cpu?

commit page:https://github.com/golang/go/commit/ca8354843ef9f30207efd0a40bb6c53e7ba86892

Comment: Could you provide details like code version of this "a recent revision change", for others to check?

Comment: It appears that [this](https://github.com/golang/go/commit/ca8354843ef9f30207efd0a40bb6c53e7ba86892) is the commit you are referring to (three years ago so not that recent!). The comment mentions inlining but I see no mention of branch prediction?

Comment: On most ISAs, there are no explicit branch hints in assembly language, so the compiler can't hint even if it wanted to.  However, laying out the hot path through a function so it's contiguous can be a win, not exactly because of branch *prediction*, as in [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7346929/what-is-the-advantage-of-gccs-builtin-expect-in-if-else-statements/31540623#31540623).  Related: [Is there a compiler hint for GCC to force branch prediction to always go a certain way?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30136196)

Comment: @PeterCordes Can I understand that it is the responsibility of the CPU，that I delete the if done==1 branch in my code and I trust the CPU can handle this?

Comment: If such questions come up in the future: Ask them on the golang-nuts mailing list.

Answer (score 1):

[The particular commit you're talking about](https://github.com/golang/go/commit/ca8354843ef9f30207efd0a40bb6c53e7ba86892) (found by [Brits in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73536470/is-branch-prediction-purely-cpu-behavior-or-will-the-compiler-give-some-hints#comment129858017_73536470)) is not an attempt to make use of *branch prediction*.  It's using knowledge about how the Go compiler does inline expansion of small functions.

We're given the option of writing a function in this way:

```
func (o *Object) Operate() {
    if (o.alreadyDone) { return }
    ... some code ...
}
```

Or, alternatively, writing it this way:

```
func (o *Object) Operate() {
    if (!o.alreadyDone) { o.reallyOperate() }
}
```

where `o.reallyOperate` takes over the `... some code ...` part.

If the `some code` part is more than a few instructions long and is written the way the original `once.Do` was, the Go compiler implements the function by having the caller *call* the actual function.  But when it's as short as the replacement, the caller implements the function as an inline test, branch, and then *maybe* call the `reallyOperate` function.

Since `sync.Once` actually calls the function only once per `Once` object, and the rest of the time, does not call, this inline expansion results in *not* making the call on every `Do` call *except* the first one.  This actually makes the code at the call site bigger (by one or two instructions) but since the call is normally *not executed*, the result is normally faster.

Comment: So it's manual partial-inlining of just the early-out check from a big function?  Yeah, that's a useful optimization in other languages, too, such as C: [How well do compilers (with link-time optimization) cope with functions that return quickly (early-out paths)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29706147)

Comment: I think I know what the main idea of that commit. The only thing I want to check is that does sentence 'if (o.alreadyDone) { return }' exist or not make any difference. If not, why the previous version has that? If that does has some effect, what is that and how to handle that?

Comment: @agnes: it makes a difference *to the Go compiler*, which has a particular, specific strategy for doing function inlining. Other compilers have different strategies and hence may work better with different source code tweaks.

Comment: @torek I have test that with or not 'if (o.alreadyDone) { return }', compiler can inlining despite. Did you get my point?

Comment: Did you test the version of the Go compiler that was in use at the time they changed the source?